# Why do these two different regex's return different results in Ruby based upon position of underscore

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following:.

```
[11] pry(main)> "ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9_\.-]+)/)
=> [["123-4.56"]]
[12] pry(main)> "ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9\.-_]+)/)
=> [["123"]]
```

I am unsure why the second one with the the underscore at the end behaves differently than the first. How is it being interpreted by RegEx parser to make it different?

Comment: **Close voters:** I do not see this question as a "typo error". The OP is clearly stating and asking `How is it being interpreted by RegEx parser to make it different?`. Now sure, there should be a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: not a typo - just early in the morning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have the hyphen (`-`) placed in the middle of the character class without being escaped.

Within a character class `[]`, you can place a hyphen (`-`) as the **first** or **last** character. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it (`\-`) in order to be matched.

```
"ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9_\.-]+)/)   # => '123-4.56'
"ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9\.\-_]+)/)  # => '123-4.56'
```

**Note**: You don't really need to escape the dot (`.`) either, so you could rewrite this as..

```
"ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9_.-]+)/)    # => '123-4.56'
```

Or even the following if you choose to place it in the middle of the character class.

```
"ab BN123-4.56".scan(/BN([0-9.\-_]+)/)   # => '123-4.56'
```

Comment: to complete, there is no need to escape `-` immediatly after a range or a character class shortcut: `[0-9-._]` and `[\d-._]` will work too

Comment: It is a version difference, ideone works on 1.9.3p194, I have tested it with 1.9.3p392.

Comment: After some research, this is allowed since the patch 392, and you can write too: `[[_]-.0-9]` (in other words, you can write it after all ranges or character class)

Answer (score 4):

The hyphen is messing things up, not the underscore.

`-` is a special character inside a character class, indicating a range. One way to escape it is to put it at the beginning or the end of the class: `[...-]`.

So `[_.-]` checks for a character, either `_` or `.` or `-`.

And `[.-_]` check for a character, in the range "from `.` to `_`".

**Illustration**

`BN([0-9.\-_]+)` does [what you expect](http://regex101.com/r/jC9eK5) and selects `123-4.56` from `ab BN123-4.56`.

Comment: right, makes sense now. up at 5 in the morning coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen inside of square brackets [] indicates a range. To use a literal hyphen escape it like you do special characters with a \